# Snell's Law using Calculus for smooth curves

Tags: calculus

I hope this does not conflict with the purpose of this site, so I will be as clear as I can.

So I know this seems like a simple equation, I know that it revolves mostly with refractive index and reflective index depending on which one you use. That light bends or reflects at different velocities depending on the medium it passes through, you can calculate based on different angles and at least one index.

And I know that in some experiments that a light beam can curve smoothly if introduced to a inconsistent index, I have been looking for the method to at least do the calculus for the Snell's Law for adding different variations. At first I was redirected to using Fermat's Principle of least time or to Taylor's Series which uses multiple variations for the similar equation.

and example would be a water tank with table salt that shining a light through it would cause the beam to curve downward. this is usually called Gradient refractive Index

I hope this is simple and that someone can point me in the right direction as to how to start it.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you mean. You should explain more. Do you consider that light passes through a medium with a continuously varying index ? This is achieved in some optical fibers

Comment: @JeanMarie I made the edit to add more detail, I added how a certain medium with a varying index causes the light beam to curve, which is what I wish to know of out to calculate.

Comment: @Semiclassical it is, I will remove it.

Comment: If you're working with a medium with continuously varying refractive index, you won't be able to do a simple differential calculus max/min problem; you'll have to use the calculus of variations.

Comment: @TedShifrin That is fine, I that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Have a look at some of the classical solutions to the [Brachistochrone problem]. The equations you’ll need to formulate and solve will be similar.

Comment: Okay so I was looking up said information to try out the Brachistochrone Problem for Snell's Law, and it says that:

If we now apply Snell's Law at each of these interfaces , we obtain

sin(theta)/constant value equaling multiple layers

In other words, the ratio would still be sin(theta)/constant value

http://www.math.wpi.edu/Course_Materials/MA1024A97/projects/project2.html